# jquery how to fill li's on top of li inside ul

Tags: jquery, html-lists

Suppose i have ul with one li as shown below

```
    <ul class="creatures_list" style="display:block">
      <li class='list_creatures'><a href="#"><b>Add Creatures</b></a></li>
   </ul>
```

What i want is insert more li's on top of given li using jQuery example as below

```
 <ul class="creatures_list" style="display:block">
     <li class='list_creatures'><a href='#'>1</a></li>
     <li class='list_creatures'><a href='#'>2</a></li>
     <li class='list_creatures'><a href='#'>3</a></li>
     <li class='list_creatures'><a href='#'>4</a></li>
     <li class='list_creatures'><a href="#"><b>Add Creatures</b></a></li>
 </ul>
```

I hope it is understandable. Awating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting to click the "Add Creature" link and add to the `<ul>`? That's what this will do, sorry if I am not understanding the question.

[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/adaca4/2/)

```
var liCount = $('.creatures_list').children().size();

$('.add_creature').click(function(){
  $(this).before('<li><a href="##" class="list_creatures">'+liCount+++'</a></li>');
  return false;
});​
```

Comment: Yes You are absolutely right. Thats exactly i want to do. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.creatures_list').prepend(function() {

   var html;

   for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
       html += "<li class='list_creatures'><a href='#'>" + i + "</a></li>";
   }

   return html;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $last_child =  $('.creatures_list').children('.list_creatures').last();

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $last_child.before("<li class='list_creatures'><a href='#'>" + (i + 1) + "</a></li>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution will increment the number correctly and keep them in ascending order:

```
var numCreatures = 0;

function addCreature() {
   $(".creatures_list li:last").before(
      "<li class='list_creatures'><a href='#'>" + ++numCreatures + "</a></li>"
   );
}
```

You can call addCreature whenever you want, for example when someone clicks on the last `<li>`:

```
$(".creatures_list li:last").click(addCreature);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

```
$('#creatures_list').prepend('<li class="list_creatures"><a href="#">1</a></li>';
```